# Python unit test that uses an external data file

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a Python project that I'm working on in Eclipse and I have the following file structure:

```
/Project
    /projectname
        module1.py
        module2.py 
        # etc.
    /test
        testModule1.py
        # etc.
        testdata.csv
```

In one of my tests I create an instance of one of my classes giving `'testdata.csv'` as a parameter. This object does `open('testdata.csv')` and reads the contents.

If I run just this single test file with `unittest` everything works and the file is found and read properly. However if I try to run all my unit tests (i.e. run by right clicking the `test` directory rather than the individual test file), I get an error that file could not be found.

Is there any way to get around this (other than providing an absolute path, which I'd prefer not to do)?

Comment: Why not make it accept the filename as relative to `__file__`? Or see [here](https://github.com/textbook/py_wlc/blob/develop/tests/data/test_webtag_data.py#L9) where I've assumed tests are run in the project root.

Comment: Oh that's a pretty good idea using os.getcwd to avoid absolute path. I'll try that

Comment: That will break if it isn't run from `Project`, though! Now I look at it, maybe starting with `os.path.dirname(__file__)` would be better

Comment: Updated, and still passing the CI: https://github.com/textbook/py_wlc/blob/develop/tests/data/test_webtag_data.py#L9 (docs are apparently broken, but that seems to be unrelated!)

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work great.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Usually what I do is define

`THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

at the top of each test module. Then it doesn't matter what working directory you're in - the file path is always the same relative to the where the test module sits.

Then I use something like this is in my test (or test setup):

```
my_data_path = os.path.join(THIS_DIR, os.pardir, 'data_folder/data.csv')
```

Or in your case, since the data source is in the test directory:

```
my_data_path = os.path.join(THIS_DIR, 'testdata.csv')
```

**Edit: for modern python**

```
from pathlib import Path

THIS_DIR = Path(__file__).parent

my_data_path = THIS_DIR.parent / 'data_folder/data.csv'

# or if it's in the same directory
my_data_path = THIS_DIR / 'testdata.csv'
```

Comment: Adding this here as well, if you wanna go back in directories use /../ example: 
template_path = f"{THIS_DIR}/../../my-template.yaml"

Comment: Alternatively `Path(__file__).parents[2]`

Answer (score 17):

Unit test that access the file system are generally not a good idea. This is because the test should be self contained, by making your test data external to the test it's no longer immediately obvious which test the csv file belongs to or even if it's still in use.

A preferable solution is to patch `open` and make it return a file-like object.

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open

from textwrap import dedent

class OpenTest(TestCase):
    DATA = dedent("""
        a,b,c
        x,y,z
        """).strip()

    @patch("builtins.open", mock_open(read_data=DATA))
    def test_open(self):

        # Due to how the patching is done, any module accessing `open' for the 
        # duration of this test get access to a mock instead (not just the test 
        # module).
        with open("filename", "r") as f:
            result = f.read()

        open.assert_called_once_with("filename", "r")
        self.assertEqual(self.DATA, result)
        self.assertEqual("a,b,c\nx,y,z", result)
```

Comment: What about larger (1.5 MB in my example) binary files? I need to test a function that parses a binary data file.

Comment: Unit tests are meant to be small and encapsulated. My first question would be why does a unit test need 1.5 MB of data? From an outside perspective it would be very hard to verify that the test is correct, or what to do if the test was to break at a later date.  If you really do need that data  then it sounds more like an integration test rather than a unit-test that is trying to test a small sub-component of the code. It's fine for integration tests to not be encapsulated (use the file system, or a database, etc...), just keep them separated from your unit tests.

Comment: The library's purpose is to load binary data files which happen to be 1.5MB in size. It is a file format parser. Still, thanks for your answer: I will try to separate the tests, but that does not solve a lot. I have some unit tests which do not access the file system and some integration tests which access the file system then. I used the solution by Jamie Bull for the latter.

Answer (score 6):

For test discovery it is [recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) to make your test folder a package. In this case you can access resources in the test folder using [*importlib.resources*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) (mind Python version compatibility of the individual functions, there are backports available as [*importlib_resources*](https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)), as described [here](https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#example), e.g. like:

```
import importlib.resources

test_file_path_str = str(importlib.resources.files('tests').joinpath('testdata.csv'))
test_function_expecting_filename(test_file_path_str)
```

Like this you do not need to rely on inferring file locations of your code.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the best way to handle these cases is to program via inversion of control.

In the two sections below I primarily show how a no-inversion-of-control solution would look like. The second section shows a solution with inversion of control and how this code can be tested without a mocking-framework.

In the end I state some personal pros and cons that do not at all have the intend to be correct and or complete. Feel free to comment for augmentation and correction.

### No inversion of control (no dependency injection)

You have a class that uses the std `open` method from python.

```
class UsesOpen(object):
  def some_method(self, path):
    with open(path) as f:
      process(f)

# how the class is being used in the open
def main():
  uses_open = UsesOpen()
  uses_open.some_method('/my/path')
```

Here I have used `open` explicitly in my code, so the only way to write tests for it would be to use **explicit test-data** (files) or use a **mocking-framework** like Dunes suggests.
But there is still another way:

### My suggestion: Inversion of control (with dependency injection)

Now I rewrote the class differently:

```
class UsesOpen(object):
  def __init__(self, myopen):
    self.__open = myopen

  def some_method(self, path):
    with self.__open(path) as f:
      process(f)

# how the class is being used in the open
def main():
  uses_open = UsesOpen(open)
  uses_open.some_method('/my/path')
```

In this second example I injected the dependency for `open` into the constructor (Constructor Dependency Injection).

#### Writing tests for inversion of control

Now I can easily write tests and use my test version of `open` when I need it:

```
EXAMPLE_CONTENT = """my file content
as an example
this can be anything"""

TEST_FILES = {
  '/my/long/fake/path/to/a/file.conf': EXAMPLE_CONTENT
}

class MockFile(object):
  def __init__(self, content):
    self.__content = content
  def read(self):
    return self.__content

  def __enter__(self):
    return self
  def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
    pass

class MockFileOpener(object):
  def __init__(self, test_files):
    self.__test_files = test_files

  def open(self, path, *args, **kwargs):
    return MockFile(self.__test_files[path])

class TestUsesOpen(object):
  def test_some_method(self):
    test_opener = MockFileOpener(TEST_FILES)

    uses_open = UsesOpen(test_opener.open)

    # assert that uses_open.some_method('/my/long/fake/path/to/a/file.conf')
    # does the right thing
```

### Pro/Con

Pro Dependency Injection

- no need to learn mocking framework for tests
- complete control over the classes and methods that have to be faked
- also changing and evolving your code is easier in general
- code quality normally improves, as one of the most important
  factors is being able to respond to changes as easy as possible
- using dependency injection and a dependency injection framework
  is generally a respected way to work on a project https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Con Dependency Injection

- a little bit more code to write in general
- in tests not as short as patching a class via @patch
- constructors can get overloaded with dependencies
- you need to somehow *learn* to use dependency-injection

Comment: You can combine DI and Mocks by injecting unittest.mocks into the class. So you can omit using patch but still use mock.return_value without the need to implement a complete MockClass.

Answer (score -6):

Your tests should not open the file directly, every test should copy the file and work with its copy.

Comment: That still leaves the problem of *figuring out where the original is*!

Comment: You may try this: sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('/home/user/Project/FolderWithTests'))

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense at all. Given that you're starting with an absolute path (which, remember, the OP doesn't want in the first place), why pass it to `abspath`? I would generally leave altering `sys.path` at runtime as a last resort - there are usually much neater solutions.

Comment: I think you mean *my* `conf.py`, where it's taking relative paths and making them absolute, which is not what you're suggesting. Please don't give bad advice.

Comment: Out of curiosity can you or anyone elaborate on this statement? Why is it bad practice to open a file directly in my tests?

Comment: It's (can be) bad practice to test on a file from a test directory since you may end up with your test file being out of sync with the one your real code is using. I literally just found a bug where this was the problem.